# What's the probability of buying 5 tickets, so that each ticket will be for a movie from a different country?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the correct way to solve the following question:

There are 50 movies in a cinema. 20 French movies, 20 American movies, 8 Chinese movies, 1 Italian movie, 1 Japanese movie.

5 tickets were bought randomly. What's the probability of buying 5 tickets, so that each ticket will be for a movie from a different country?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question by means of an edit (not a comment), and tell us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little unclear, so I will make the following assumptions; let me know if these assumptions are incorrect and I will edit the answer:

1. It is possible to select the same movie 5 times.
2. You are asking for the probability that the 5 movies you selected are from 5 different countries.
3. Order of selection is irrelevant.

For probabilities, the general equation is the number of desired outcomes over the total number of outcomes. We know that 5 movies are selected, so we will first figure out the total number of possible outcomes when 5 movies are selected. There are 50 total movies, and you are selecting 5, so the total number of possible combinations is $ _{50}C_{5} $ or $ C(50,5) $. So, $ C(50,5) $ is the denominator in the desired over total outcomes equation. To find the number of desired outcomes, we will determine the number of possible ways to select 1 of each of the 5 movies. 
There are 20 French movies, so the probability of choosing 1 French movie is $ C(20,1) $. 
There are 20 American movies, so the probability of choosing 1 American movie is $ C(20,1) $. 
There are 8 Chinese movies, so the probability of choosing 1 Chinese movie is $ C(8,1) $. 
There is 1 Italian movie, so the probability of choosing 1 Italian movie is $ C(1,1) $. 
There is 1 Japanese movie, so the probability of choosing 1 Japanese movie is $ C(1,1) $. 
Now, we multiply all these values to get the probability:
$$ \frac{C(20,1)\times C(20,1)\times C(8,1)\times C(1,1)\times C(1,1)}{C(50,5)} $$
Now, let's simplify. For integer values of n, C(n,1) = n. So, we can simplify the numerator:
$$ \frac{20\times 20\times 8\times 1\times 1}{C(50,5)} $$
For the denominator, we can use the equation of a combination:
 $$ C(n,r) = \frac{n!}{r!\times (n - r)!} $$
Plug in the values of C(50,5) into the equation, and simplify to get the solution. For problems about combinations (where the numerators and denominators involve quite a bit of multiplying) wait to multiply out the top and bottom of the fraction until the end, since you can usually simplify.
$$ \frac{20\times 20\times 8\times 1\times 1}{\frac{50!}{5!\times (50 - 5)!}} $$
$$= \frac{20\times 20\times 8}{\frac{50!}{5!\times 45!}} $$
$$ =\frac{20\times 20\times 8}{\frac{50\times 49\times 48\times 47\times 46\times 45!}{5!\times 45!}} $$
Cancel out the $ 45! $ in the numerator and denominator:
$$ =\frac{20\times 20\times 8}{\frac{50\times 49\times 48\times 47\times 46}{5!}} $$
Continue to cancel out and multiply out until you get your solution:
$$ =\frac{20\times 20\times 8 \times 5!}{50\times 49\times 48\times 47\times 46} $$
$$ =\frac{20\times 20\times 8 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1}{50\times 49\times 48\times 47\times 46} $$
$$ =\frac{20\times 20\times (8 \times 3 \times 2) \times 5 \times 4 \times 1}{50\times 49\times 48\times 47\times 46} $$
$$ =\frac{20\times 20\times (46) \times 5 \times 4 \times 1}{50\times 49\times 48\times 47\times 46} $$
$$ =\frac{20\times 20\times 5 \times 4}{50\times 49\times 48\times 47} $$
$$ =\frac{20\times (20\times 5) \times 4}{50\times 49\times 48\times 47} $$
$$ =\frac{20\times (100) \times 4}{50\times 49\times 48\times 47} $$
$$ =\frac{20\times (2) \times 4}{49\times 48\times 47} $$
$$ =\frac{20\times (2 \times 4)}{49\times 48\times 47} $$
$$ =\frac{20\times (8)}{49\times 48\times 47} $$
$$ =\frac{20}{49\times 6\times 47} $$
$$ =\frac{10}{49\times 3\times 47} $$
$$ =\frac{10}{6909} $$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Figure out the number of ways you can get 5 tickets for movies from 5 different countries

Also figure out the number of ways to get 5 tickets, period.

Divide the first number by the second, and you have the probability.

Here's a question you need to answer: When getting 5 random tickets, is it possible to get multiple tickets for the very same movie?

Below, I'll cover both options.

**A. First, let's assume you *can* end up with multiple tickets to the same movie:**

There are $50^5$ possible outcomes, assuming we do order the tickets. Now, if want all tickets to be from different countries, then you have $20 \cdot 20 \cdot 8 \cdot 1 \cdot 1$ possibilitites, But, since we ordered all the possible outcomes, we should like order these, meaning that we multiply by $5!$ for all ordered series of $5$ tickets from all different countries. In sum, the probability is:

$$\frac{20 \cdot 20 \cdot 8 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 5!}{50^5}$$

**B. Now let's consider the case where the $5$ tickets cannot be from the same movie, i.e. what if the $5$ random tickets all have to be from different movies?**

Well, the number of (ordered) possibilities is $50\cdot 49 \cdot 48 \cdot 47 \cdot 46$, and so the the probability is:

$$\frac{20 \cdot 20 \cdot 8 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 5!}{50\cdot 49 \cdot 48 \cdot 47 \cdot 46}$$

We can solve this second problem as follows as well: without repeat tickets, there are ${50} \choose 5$ possible ticket options, though this time they are unordered. And, we have $20 \cdot 20 \cdot 8 \cdot 1 \cdot 1$ unordered groups of $5$ tickets from all $5$ different countries, so the probability is:

$$\frac{20 \cdot 20 \cdot 8 \cdot 1 \cdot 1}{{50}\choose 5}$$

These last two probabilities should be the same of course, but since

$${{50}\choose 5}=\frac{50!}{45!5!}=\frac{50\cdot 49 \cdot 48 \cdot 47 \cdot 46}{5!}$$

it is easily verified that they are.

Now, if the $5$ tickets are bought truly randomly, then I would personally think that the first scenario (scenario A) makes the most sense. The second scenario B would make sense if someone bought $1$ ticket from each movie before hand, and then had me randomly pick $5$ of those, but that doesn't seem to quite match the problem statement.  It seems more like I go up to the counter, and $5$ times, a random selection of all $50$ is movies is being made. So, my final answer is the answer compatible with scenario A, i.e.:

$$\frac{20 \cdot 20 \cdot 8 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 5!}{50^5}$$

which works out to:

$$\frac{96}{78125}$$

or

$$0.0012288$$

Comment: I edited the question,maybe I misphrased it. 
Can you check out the new edit please?

Comment: @Liorddd  It is still not clear whether, when buying 5 random tickets, you can end up with tickets to the exact same movie, e.g. 5 tickets to that 1 Italian movie.  I know that that is not the *desired* outcome, but my question is whether or not that is a *possible* outcome

Comment: @Liorddd It is still not clear what scenario you are looking for ... so I have added the answer to both possibilities.